# Is there impedance when there is nothing else?

Tags: radiation, observable-universe

With the exception of gravitational waves, all the information about the universe we gained from electro magnetic waves which we agree to run at the speed of light for all the spectrum from far infrared to gamma and beyond.

If an EM-wave meets a discontinuity in impedance it will be partly reflected. So if the universe is not infinite and doesn't expand at the speed of light, EM-Waves will eventually reach "the end" of the universe. If they are just travelling forward, the universe would expand at the speed of light. If they are reflected, we should be able to see the light in the end.

So if a huge event "takes place" close to the border of the young universe and we see the EM-Waves with a telescope, shouldn't we see the reflections at the frontier of the universe too?

Is this question anywhere opened in a more scientific manner?

Comment: Even with a steady-state universe, there's no need to assume a discontinuity. Consider an [n dimensional sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) with no boundary in any of the first three dimensions.

Comment: @JiminyCricket The "Universe" I selected is not specified explicitely. It's a principal question: is the impedance 377 Ohm of the vacuum something that exists even if there is no EM-energy. I do not believe in wormholes and perpetua mobile. I see curved space-time as something real and independ of any mathematical model.